# How to compile a MS Word add-in project for AppSource on a Mac

Tags: macos, ms-word, office-store, appsource

I've created an MS Word add-in using my Mac, and want to begin the process of submitting it for validation to AppSource. However, the process requires a package to be uploaded, and I haven't been able to find any documentation whatsoever on how to compile my project into the sort of package expected.

The page where you upload your package lists the following file types as being acceptable: `.msix, .msixbundle, .msixupload, .appx, .appxbundle, .appxupload, .xap`. I've downloaded Visual Studio for Mac, as there's some documents which describe using VS to compile a project to these sorts of packages, but see no way to import my existing project folder – nor any way to start a new Word Add-in project (or anything that sounds similar.)

My project is a React-based add-in created using the Yeoman office project generator (https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office), consisting of your standard React project structure (package.json, webpack config files, src/components) as well as my manifest.xml file.

Edit:

To be clear, there is indeed a place within the Submission process which says:

```
Drag your packages here (.msix, .msixbundle, .msixupload, .appx, .appxbundle, .appxupload, .xap) or browse your files.
```

However, when I attempt to upload my `manifest.xml` file using this interface, I receive the following errors:

```
- You must provide a package that supports each selected device family (or uncheck the box for unsupported device families). Note that targeting the Xbox device family requires a neutral or x64 package.

- You must upload at least one package. If you are using market groups, then each market group must have at least one package.

- You must fix all package validation errors before submitting.

- Package acceptance validation error: manifest.xml is an unknown package type. Please name your file with the appropriate file extension.
```

I've used manifest validation tools on my current manifest, and they tell me it's structurally valid as well as possesses all required fields. This, as well as the list of accepted filetypes mentioned in my comment below, is what leads me to believe that I'm expected to upload a specific compiled package type.

Answer (score 0):

In order to submit a Word add-in for publication to AppSource you need to submit your add-in via the [Seller Dashboard](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248605). You will need to submit a [.xml manifest file.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/upload-package)

For more information on how to submit your add-in to SellerDashboard please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/use-the-seller-dashboard-to-submit-to-the-office-store).

Comment: Just to be clear, do you mean to upload it at the prompt where it says `Drag your packages here (.msix, .msixbundle, .msixupload, .appx, .appxbundle, .appxupload, .xap) or browse your files.`? Because if so, I get the error which I'm going to edit into my question above.

Comment: Hi Mike - It seems like you are trying to upload via AppSource. To submit Office Add-ins to AppSource you need to upload via the [SellerDashboard](https://sellerdashboard.microsoft.com)

Comment: Could you please take a look at my subsequent post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714267/continuing-issues-uploading-word-add-in-project-manifest-to-appsource I've included screenshots as well. The instructions you're giving don't seem to correspond to any options I have available to me.

Comment: Looks like this answer is now out of date. Any update since this was now moved to partner center?