# How do I upload a Word Add-in to AppSource from the Seller Dashboard?

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-js, office-store, appsource

We've spent a week or two trying to get the ability to use the SellerDashboard to upload a Word Addin, but no luck. We've also been on the phone, live chat, screen share, and have support tickets with Microsoft - but still no luck. So, looking to the community for help.

I've already read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714267/continuing-issues-uploading-word-add-in-project-manifest-to-appsource), but that user was trying to upload in the wrong place - whereas I have all the correct permissions, but am stuck in an infinite loop.

1: Go to Partner Center >> click on "Office Store" >> click on "Overview"/"Client IDs"/"Office Profile"

[image: Step 1 of the office re-direct problem]

2: Get re-directed to https://sellerdashboard.microsoft.com/Registration

[image: Step 2 of the office re-direct problem]

3: Click "Continue" under Office

4: Get re-directed to https://partner.microsoft.com/en-US/dashboard/Office/signup

[image: Step 4 of the office re-direct problem]

5: Click "Sign up now"

6: Get re-directed to https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/Account/Management?accountProgram=Office

[image: Step 6 of office re-direct problem]

7: Twiddle thumbs

So, basically, I can keep doing this ad-infinitum, and there is no way out. I've added our company as a tenant, I've added our Microsoft users as users, everything I can link up - is linked up.

Here's the craziest part. The "owner" of this Partner Center account doesn't get caught in this loop.

After step 1, he is re-directed to https://sellerdashboard.microsoft.com/Application/Summary and has the option to start creation of an Add-In (but I'm the developer of the add-in, so I need to upload the manifest and fill in everything, make tweaks, etc).

I've tried using Chrome, Incognito Chrome (no Chrome extensions), and Safari - but no luck.

I'm not blocking any cookies, but still no luck.

I see in Chrome Dev Tools that there are a lot of errors when I go to the Seller Dashboard, but there's nothing I can do about that.

Has anyone run into anything like this, and are there any suggestions? It's hard enough even getting the correct support team on the phone, without getting re-directed all over the place.

**UPDATE MAY 28:**

After 2.5 weeks of waiting for Microsoft Support, the closest thing to an "answer" I received about this problem was that only the Owner of the account (e.g. the first person to create an account, using their PERSONAL Microsoft credentials) can create apps, upload them, etc etc...

> "but once directed to the actual seller dashboard, only the owner of
>   the Microsoft account can access these features. This is by design"

This is so thoroughly insane that I don't even believe this is really the answer, and that there must be a misunderstanding somewhere. Because, it basically means that if the person who created the Seller Dashboard account leaves a company, then you no longer have access to your product in the Office Store.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because customer support questions are off-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've both released add-ins through my personal account also work for a company where multiple people has access to Office store.

1. You have to use an MSA when signing up. (Outlook.com / hotmail.com accounts). Organizational IDs won't work.
2. We have a shared account, which we use to publish / unpublish add-ins. Credential of this account is generally stored with whoever(s) is / are coordinating the release of the add-in and not the development team. It's fine though because we have multiple people with the sign-in credentials.
3. In terms of steps, you are not that far off. Basically head off to https://sellerdashboard.microsoft.com/Registration and follow the steps on (which should lead you to link below). When you're signed-in, make sure from the top right window that you're actually signed in with the personal account and not your organizational account. I find the organizational accounts to be very sticky in terms of sign-in.
4. https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/registration/AccountInfo?accountProgram=Office go through this experience. Once created the account, the validation of it should take a few days. Then you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for this reply - it's not exactly the answer I was looking for, but it's as close as I think we'll get on SO, and it closely answers the question as I've asked it. In speaking with Microsoft, the problem I was trying to solve is basically unsolvable. It's worth really noting that the Microsoft account who creates the account is forever the owner and this can never be changed - so, as you mentioned, you should create a new account just for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be redirected to Partner Center if your browser is also signed in with an AAD account. Seller Dashboard can only be used via an MSA account.

Could you try open sellerdashboard.microsoft.com in a private browser session and ensure you are only signed in with an MSA account?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alan, still the same problem. I noticed one very peculiar thing, which is that my sellerdashboard doesn't have a left-navigation bar of any sort. But, again, I've tried most permutations of accounts and Chrome Incognito-ness - with no luck. It feels like it's a permission thing (and I've given max permissions to all users), or a bug in the platform.